# Using LG open Source software for LG B460 Mobile Phone

Tags: lg

I have an LG true flip phone model number:LG B460 Software Version: B46010d
Imei:014109008852959
I'm working on a project where I have to change the length of time the phone vibrates for when a message is received and possibly more.

I'm still not sure whether I can edit the firmware or opensource software but,
I found some open source software for LG phones at opensource.lge.com/osList/list?m=Mc001&s=Sc002.

You can perform a search for LGB460 using CTRL+F and download the zip file. 
Does anyone have any idea how to edit this kind of code?
I found a txt file that suggests spidermonkey by mozilla was used (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)

I don't understand how to build or even begin to use spidermonkey much less understand the phone's source code I downloaded, even if I open it on spidermonkey.  If anyone has any suggestions on how to use this open source code for the phone to adjust the length of vibration time please let me know.

Furthermore if you can use the phone's Open source code, how do you save it as a KDZ firmware file or how can it be placed to run on the phone.

Thanks a lot.